# Clip content of a whole JComponent and it's children

Tags: swing, awt, graphics2d

I'm trying to clip the content of a tree of component (simply a JPanel with childs). In particular I'd like to clip around the edges, the panel is intended to be used as an overlay.

And I've found this to be really difficult to achieve. For example this snippet which tries to wrap the content by a overriding the `paintComponent` does not produce the intended effect.

[image]

```kotlin
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.MagicConstant
import java.awt.BorderLayout
import java.awt.Color
import java.awt.Graphics
import java.awt.Graphics2D
import java.awt.RenderingHints
import java.awt.geom.Path2D
import javax.swing.BorderFactory
import javax.swing.JComponent
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JLabel
import javax.swing.JPanel
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities

open class Wrapper(content: JComponent) : JPanel(BorderLayout()) {
    init {
        add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER)
    }
}

/**
 * A panel that clips its background (capture from its content component) to the top or bottom.
 *
 * In order to properly show clipped background, it disables the opacity
 * on the `content` component and captures its background color.
 */
private class BackgroundClippingPanel(
    @MagicConstant(intValues = [CLIP_TOP.toLong(), CLIP_BOTTOM.toLong()]) private val cornerClipping: Int,
    content: JComponent
) : Wrapper(content) {
    companion object {
        const val CLIP_TOP = 0b01
        const val CLIP_BOTTOM = 0b10
    }

    private val arc = 20f

    init {
        content.isOpaque = false
        background = content.background
        size = content.size
        preferredSize = content.preferredSize
        minimumSize = content.minimumSize
        maximumSize = content.maximumSize
        isOpaque = true
    }

    override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics?) {
        val g2 = g as Graphics2D
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE)

        val clipRegion = Path2D.Float().apply {
            val adj = .5f
            val w = width.toFloat() - adj
            val h = height.toFloat() - adj

            if (cornerClipping and CLIP_TOP == CLIP_TOP) {
                moveTo(0f, arc)
                // top left corner
                curveTo(0f, 0f, arc, 0f)
                lineTo(w - arc, 0f)
                // top right corner
                curveTo(w, 0f, w, arc)
            } else {
                moveTo(0f, 0f)
                lineTo(w, 0f)
            }

            if (cornerClipping and CLIP_BOTTOM == CLIP_BOTTOM) {
                lineTo(w, h - arc)
                // bottom right corner
                curveTo(w, h, w - arc, h)
                lineTo(arc, h)
                // bottom left corner
                curveTo(0f, h, 0f, h - arc)
            } else {
                lineTo(w, h)
                lineTo(0f, h)
            }
            closePath()
        }
        val oldClip = g2.clip
        g2.clip = clipRegion
        super.paintComponent(g)
        g2.clip = oldClip
    }

    private fun Path2D.Float.curveTo(
        controlPointX: Float,
        controlPointY: Float,
        endPointX: Float,
        endPointY: Float
    ) {
        curveTo(controlPointX, controlPointY, controlPointX, controlPointY, endPointX, endPointY)
    }
}

fun main() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
        val contentThatNeedToBeClipped = JPanel(BorderLayout()).apply {
            add(
                JLabel("Should be clipped on top").apply {
                    background = Color(0xD4D4D4)
                    isOpaque = true
                    border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 5)
                },
                BorderLayout.NORTH
            )
            add(
                JLabel("Main content").apply {
                    background = Color(0xF1F1F1)
                    border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 5)
                },
                BorderLayout.CENTER
            )
            add(
                JLabel("Should be clipped on bottom").apply {
                    background = Color(0xD4D4D4)
                    isOpaque = true
                    border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 5)
                },
                BorderLayout.SOUTH
            )
        }

        // don't work
        val clippedContent = BackgroundClippingPanel(
            BackgroundClippingPanel.CLIP_TOP or BackgroundClippingPanel.CLIP_BOTTOM,
            contentThatNeedToBeClipped
        )

        val frameContent = JPanel(BorderLayout()).apply {
            background = Color(0x333333)
            border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30)
            add(clippedContent)
        }

        val f = JFrame().apply {
            defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
            setSize(400, 400)
            contentPane = frameContent
            isVisible = true
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I want to achieve clipping I actually need to modify my hierarchy to install the Clipping component. Like wrapping my top and bottom component, and tweaking the background of the container.

This looks like the code gets more brittle along the way.

[image]

```kotlin
import BackgroundClippingPanel.Companion.clipBottom
import BackgroundClippingPanel.Companion.clipTop
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.MagicConstant
import java.awt.BorderLayout
import java.awt.Color
import java.awt.Graphics
import java.awt.Graphics2D
import java.awt.RenderingHints
import java.awt.geom.Path2D
import javax.swing.BorderFactory
import javax.swing.JComponent
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JLabel
import javax.swing.JPanel
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities

open class Wrapper(content: JComponent) : JPanel(BorderLayout()) {
    init {
        add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER)
    }
}

/**
 * A panel that clips its background (capture from its content component) to the top or bottom.
 *
 * In order to properly show clipped background, it disables the opacity
 * on the `content` component and captures its background color.
 */
private class BackgroundClippingPanel(
    @MagicConstant(intValues = [CLIP_TOP.toLong(), CLIP_BOTTOM.toLong()]) private val cornerClipping: Int,
    content: JComponent
) : Wrapper(content) {
    companion object {
        const val CLIP_TOP = 0b01
        const val CLIP_BOTTOM = 0b10

        fun <T : JComponent> T.clipTop() = BackgroundClippingPanel(
            BackgroundClippingPanel.CLIP_TOP,
            this
        )

        fun <T : JComponent> T.clipBottom() = BackgroundClippingPanel(
            BackgroundClippingPanel.CLIP_BOTTOM,
            this
        )
    }

    private val arc = 20f

    init {
        content.isOpaque = false
        background = content.background
        size = content.size
        preferredSize = content.preferredSize
        minimumSize = content.minimumSize
        maximumSize = content.maximumSize
        isOpaque = true
    }

    override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics?) {
        val g2 = g as Graphics2D
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE)

        val clipRegion = Path2D.Float().apply {
            val adj = .5f
            val w = width.toFloat() - adj
            val h = height.toFloat() - adj

            if (cornerClipping and CLIP_TOP == CLIP_TOP) {
                moveTo(0f, arc)
                // top left corner
                curveTo(0f, 0f, arc, 0f)
                lineTo(w - arc, 0f)
                // top right corner
                curveTo(w, 0f, w, arc)
            } else {
                moveTo(0f, 0f)
                lineTo(w, 0f)
            }

            if (cornerClipping and CLIP_BOTTOM == CLIP_BOTTOM) {
                lineTo(w, h - arc)
                // bottom right corner
                curveTo(w, h, w - arc, h)
                lineTo(arc, h)
                // bottom left corner
                curveTo(0f, h, 0f, h - arc)
            } else {
                lineTo(w, h)
                lineTo(0f, h)
            }
            closePath()
        }
        val oldClip = g2.clip
        g2.clip = clipRegion
        super.paintComponent(g)
        g2.clip = oldClip
    }

    private fun Path2D.Float.curveTo(
        controlPointX: Float,
        controlPointY: Float,
        endPointX: Float,
        endPointY: Float
    ) {
        curveTo(controlPointX, controlPointY, controlPointX, controlPointY, endPointX, endPointY)
    }
}

fun main() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
        val contentThatNeedToBeClipped = JPanel(BorderLayout()).apply {
            add(
                JLabel("Should be clipped on top").apply {
                    background = Color(0xD4D4D4)
                    isOpaque = true
                    border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 5)
                }.clipTop(),
                BorderLayout.NORTH
            )
            add(
                JLabel("Main content").apply {
                    background = Color(0xF1F1F1)
                    isOpaque = true // Somewhat replaces the container background
                    border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 5)
                },
                BorderLayout.CENTER
            )
            add(
                JLabel("Should be clipped on bottom").apply {
                    background = Color(0xD4D4D4)
                    isOpaque = true
                    border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 5)
                }.clipBottom(),
                BorderLayout.SOUTH
            )
        }.apply {
            isOpaque = false // otherwise the background color will be painted on below the clipped region
        }

        val frameContent = JPanel(BorderLayout()).apply {
            background = Color(0x333333)
            border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30)
            add(contentThatNeedToBeClipped)
        }

        val f = JFrame().apply {
            defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
            setSize(400, 400)
            contentPane = frameContent
            isVisible = true
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't there a simpler alternative e.g. as simple as setting `graphics.setClip(RoundRectangle2D.Float(...))` ?

Note, I don't want to paint the component on a BufferedImage, I need these to be fully active.

---

PS: I've searched similar questions, and I didn't found something similar to this question.